# Watch a folder constantly for new files

Tags: windows, macos, directory, wget

I have a web folder on a `Mac` (running `MAMP Pro`) and have files been added within it on the fly, whose `URL` is as follows . 
http://abc.com/folder/

I have another `Windows` machine that should constantly watch this folder and download any new file that gets dumped to this `web folder` to `c:\macfolder\` (The files are always `tsv's`).

I know I can use `wget` to acquire files and run whatever program that would do this as a scheduler in windows to watch constantly, but whats the best way to watch this folder for the new files.

Thanks

P.S I do not know what are the best tags for this question. Help me out with that too.. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the directory already is mounted on Windows, your question appears to be a duplicate of this (and related) - assuming you're OK using C# to build such a tool:

[Monitoring a directory for new file creation without FileSystemWatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612311/monitoring-a-folder-for-new-file-creation-without-using-filesystemwatcher-in-ne)

If not so keen on the C# tool, there are command line solutions like this one here:

[batch file to monitor additions to download folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230976/batch-file-to-monitor-additions-to-download-folder)